# CSGO workshops: How do I override a map's settings?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

In some CSGO workshop maps, I can't seem to override certain settings such as the freeze time, whether or not bots can use grenades and whether or not players have armour or defuse kits at the start of each round (though the last one might not have to do with the maps). Some examples are [Overpass Retake A](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=917852247), [inferno_retake_a](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1317786038) and [cache_retake_a](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1317779663). I know how to adjust these settings if I'm practicing with bots offline in the official maps, but some custom maps seem to prohibit these changes.

**Main question: In general and not necessarily for the examples I gave, how would I override map settings please?**

- My thought is to **somehow unpack/unzip the bsp file find the cfg file/s** in the unpacking, edit the cfg file and then repack/create a new bsp file with the new cfg file.
- Basically, I want the same map with different settings. Most maps seem to respect default weapons or grenades but don't respect freeze time changes or enabling/disabling certain actions of bots.
- I found something called [Entspy](http://www.bagthorpe.org/bob/cofrdrbob/entspy.html) and after downloading Java, I ran Entspy and seemed to be able to overwrite the bsp file. I even deleted the old one and replaced with the edited bsp. **However**, when I exit and return to steam, the old one seems to have come back, and the new one is gone (of course I have a backup of the new one elsewhere, but it seems steam negated my deletion and replacement of the bsp file). **How do I overwrite bsp files?**

---

**Some specific issues** that serve as **guides** to answering the main question of the post. These are **not meant** to be asked to the point that asking might cause this question to become broad:

1. **Free armour/defuse kits is not given for succeeding rounds** (any map): If I execute giving free armour by '[mp_free_armor](https://totalcsgo.com/command/mpfreearmor) 1' to bots and players in a certain round, then starting next round (or for first round of next game if I immediately restart game with '[`mp_restartgame`](https://totalcsgo.com/command/mprestartgame) 1'), all bots will get armour. However unless I run '[`mp_free_armor`](https://totalcsgo.com/command/mpfreearmor) 1' again, the bots and players who died in the round where they get armour will not get armour in the succeeding round.

   - So far, my fix for this to just bind ([`bind`](https://totalcsgo.com/command/bind)) a key to give armour every round. What's the '[`mp_afterroundmoney`](https://totalcsgo.com/command/mpafterroundmoney)' version for armour? Is there another way to do this?
   - My feeling is that there's no such version for armour just as there's no such version for '[`mp_ct_default_grenades`](https://totalcsgo.com/command/mpctdefaultgrenades) "`weapon_flashbang weapon_smokegrenade`"'.
2. **Buy time** (any map): I cannot seem to extend the initial 4-5 seconds of buy time.

   - Ok, I **partly** figured out the issue here. I confused buy time ([`mp_buytime`](https://totalcsgo.com/command/mpbuytime)) for freeze time ([`mp_freezetime`](https://totalcsgo.com/command/mpfreezetime)). The freeze time is the 4-5 seconds while the buy time stretches longer than 4-5 seconds since we can buy even after being unfrozen. The problem now is...
3. **Server resets cvar/console var I think** ([`inferno_retake_a`](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1317786038)): (See (2)) If I execute a change in freeze time in the middle of a certain round, say round 1, the server accepts this change for the next round, round 2 (or for first round of next game if I immediately restart game with '[`mp_restartgame`](https://totalcsgo.com/command/mprestartgame) 1'). However, at the beginning of round 2, there is a message that says that the server resets the freeze time, which the server indeed does.

   - Of course I could bind ([`bind`](https://totalcsgo.com/command/bind)) a key to change the freeze time every round as in (1), but is there another way to do this?
   - As for the `csgo\maps\cfg` suggestion by dly in comments below, see (4).
4. Cannot prevent bots from using grenades ([`cache_retake_a`](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1317779663)): Server seems to keep ignoring '[`bot_allow_grenades`](https://totalcsgo.com/command/botallowgrenades) 0' even if were to run this command every round.

   - As suggested by dly in comments below, I found the txt file that says

> The files and folders here are examples.  When you create your real files, they should be placed in your "`\steamapps\common\Counter-Strike Global Offensive\csgo\maps\cfg`" folder if they are to function.
>
> See https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/CSGO_Custom_Game_Mode for more info.

- [Based on the link](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/CSGO_Custom_Game_Mode#Where_do_I_put_my_cfg_file.3F) in said txt file, I created a cfg with the same name as the bsp file (changed 'bsp' to 'cfg' to get `cache_retake_a.cfg`) and with '[`bot_allow_grenades`](https://totalcsgo.com/command/botallowgrenades) 0', but this didn't work.
- Was I supposed to run the cfg file? Or is it just supposed to be there? I've tried exiting the workshop and returning, but bots were still using grenades.
- Should I really put it in the '`\steamapps\common\Counter-Strike Global Offensive\csgo\maps\cfg`' folder and not the '`Steam\userdata\...\...\local\cfg`' folder? The latter is where I put all the cfg files that I run with '`exec [name].cfg`'. I notice I cannot run the '`cache_retake_a.cfg`' file while it is in the former.
- Tried putting `cache_retake_a.cfg` in the latter folder, and I was able to run it, but bots were still using grenades.

[This line is for indenting the next numbered items]

5. Cannot enable bots to defuse ([`cache_retake_a`](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1317779663)): Server seems to keep ignoring '[`bot_defer_to_human_goals`](https://totalcsgo.com/command/botdefertohumangoals) 0` even if were to run this command every round.

   - I could be understanding the command wrong, but I think setting to 0 [should enable CT bots to defuse bombs](https://steamcommunity.com/app/730/discussions/0/864972399805520485/#c864972399864866217) as they usually do, whereas this map seems to prevent CT bots from defusing. (It's probably intended for players who want to practice defusing themselves, but I'd like to have the option to try both cases: Defusing myself or relying on bots to defuse)
6. I've had some problems with some other maps such as not being able to increase the maximum number of players, but I'll omit these to not be so broad.

   - Note: I can't play some of the retake servers in the CSB, but even if I could and even for the ones where I can, it's not necessarily to the settings that I want such as what guns players and bots have.

Comment: This question is not off-topic. Setting up configs does not have anything to do with "game design". Questions like that have been accepted and answered before.

Comment: Have you tried setting up a map config for your custom map? `..csgo/cfg/maps/mapname.cfg` with your desired settings should do, unless there are not enough spawn points for your player count on that map. That's something we don't know.

Comment: @dly Thanks! I tried after I read your comment. It still didn't work because bots were still using grenades. This is what I did: I found the txt file that says 'The files and folders here are examples...real files, they should be placed in your "\steamapps\common\Counter-Strike Global Offensive\csgo\maps\cfg" folder...more info.' [Based on the link in said txt file](https://bit.ly/2LXs747), I created a cfg with the same name as the bsp file (changed 'bsp' to 'cfg') and with bot_allow_grenades 0

Comment: @dly Should I really put it in the '\steamapps\common\Counter-Strike Global Offensive\csgo\maps\cfg' folder and not the 'Steam\userdata\...\...\local\cfg' folder? The latter is where I put all the cfg files that I run with 'exec [name].cfg'. I notice I cannot run the 'cache_retake_a.cfg' file while it is in the former.

Comment: @dly Tried putting cache_retake_a.cfg in the latter folder, and I was able to run it, but bots were still using grenades. :(

Comment: When you do as stated in the Wiki you've linked the config should be loaded on map start. A manual exec shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @dly Then yeah, it doesn't work. Thanks for helping rule out the possible problems. Also, I just edited my post. Please help with Entspy, if you can.

Comment: @dly Why do you think my [other question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/351563/what-are-the-available-options-for-csgo-retake-practice) is opinion-based please? I edited to hopefully clarify.

Comment: I voted for too broad. But you should ask/discuss that there.